# iPhone GPS CLLocation lock?

Tags: iphone

How do I go about in an iPhone app, getting the user to click a button to find their location, with the CLLocation automatically locking or stopping when a good enough results is found after a few seconds?

Is there a function or an algorithm?

ie: if it finds a location with accuracy of 5m, stop, or stop after 15 seconds of trying.

Answer (score 0):

The [LocateMe](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/LocateMe/Introduction/Intro.html) sample application is a good starting point.